# How to store iterators (or something simmilar) onto harddisk?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, boost-serialization

I wanna store a huge `std::list<my_big_struct>` (but very little in this example) onto harddisk.

Further I wanna store many `std::list<std::list<my_big_struct>::const_iterator>` onto harddisk too.

How can I archive this without deep copy (would run out of space)?

Below a short example with `my_big_struct` as a simple `int`.

```
#include <list>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/list.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>

typedef int my_big_struct;

int main()
{
    std::list<my_big_struct> a = {3,2,7,4,9};
    std::list<std::list<my_big_struct>::const_iterator> aa;
    std::list<std::list<my_big_struct>::const_iterator> ab;

    std::list<my_big_struct>::const_iterator find = a.begin();
    aa.emplace(aa.begin(), find++);
    ab.emplace(ab.begin(), find);

    {
        std::ofstream f("test_a.bin", std::ios::binary);
        boost::archive::binary_oarchive o(f);
        o << a; // OK
    }

    // how to store aa and ab onto harddisk without hardcopy ???
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, how is the hard drive supposed to keep the information if it didn't deep copy the data to the hard drive? The data is lost otherwise if you don't make one.

Comment: There's no good way to store iterators, as they are meaningless without their original collection. (Iterators are for *iteration* and should normally be treated as transient.) Store offsets (`std::distance`) and then `std::advance` when you've read back the list.

Comment: a `std::list<my_big_struct>::const_iterator` just points to a location in heap memory where a `my_big_struct` is located. If you then try store that on disk and later load it back again, the location in heap memory will have changed, so all your iterators will be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the design (it sounds like a design smell to retain volatile memory relations).

If you are confident that your design is sound, I'd suggest a `managed_shared_memory` (that's Boost Interprocess).

Then, you can rely on the iterator stability of `std::list`¹.

### Demo

This demonstrates how it would work:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8674c3f33de133bd)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_mapped_file.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/list.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace bip = boost::interprocess;

typedef int my_big_struct;

namespace shared {
    using segment = bip::managed_mapped_file;
    using manager = segment::segment_manager;

    template <typename T> using alloc = bip::allocator<T, manager>;
    template <typename T> using list  = boost::interprocess::list<T, alloc<T> >;
}

int main()
{
    using List   = shared::list<my_big_struct>;
    using ItList = shared::list<List::const_iterator>;

    std::remove("test.dat");
    {
        shared::segment segment(bip::open_or_create, "test.dat", 10u<<20); // 10 megabyte

        auto& a  = *segment.find_or_construct<List>("a")(segment.get_segment_manager());
        auto& aa = *segment.find_or_construct<ItList>("aa")(segment.get_segment_manager());
        auto& ab = *segment.find_or_construct<ItList>("ab")(segment.get_segment_manager());

        a.assign({3,2,7,4,9});
        List::const_iterator find = a.begin();
        aa.emplace(aa.begin(), find++);

        ab.emplace(ab.begin(), find);
        ab.emplace(ab.begin(), std::next(find,3));
    }

    // the file is persisted
    {
        shared::segment segment(bip::open_only, "test.dat"); // read it back

        auto& a  = *segment.find_or_construct<List>("a")(segment.get_segment_manager());
        auto& ab = *segment.find_or_construct<ItList>("ab")(segment.get_segment_manager());

        for (auto iterator : ab) {
            std::cout << "Iterator in ab points to " << *iterator << " in list a\n";

            my_big_struct const* pointer = &*iterator;
            for (auto& element : a) {
                if (&element == pointer) {
                    std::cout << "Matching element is found in a (by physical address)\n";
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Prints

```
Iterator in ab points to 9 in list a
Matching element is found in a (by physical address)
Iterator in ab points to 2 in list a
Matching element is found in a (by physical address)
```

### Notes

Be prepared for some fragmentation overhead, so be careful about how you build the datastructure (if possible, manage allocations up front).

You can view some of my older answers for inspiration on Boost Interprocess

- [boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a85371%20managed_shared_memory)
- [boost::interprocess::managed_mapped_file](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a85371%20managed_mapped_file)
- [scoped_allocator_adaptor](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a85371%20scoped_allocator_adaptor) for more convenience

---

¹  Boost Interprocess manages the abstraction internally by using `offset_ptr` (you don't have to know about this implementation detail)

### More Samples

If you also want to include complex members in `my_big_struct`, you'll need to use the segment allocator there too:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/76419bda0811c162)</kbd>**

Prints

```
Iterator in ab points to my_big_struct { name:nine, value: 9 } in list a
Matching element is found in a (by physical address)
Iterator in ab points to my_big_struct { name:two, value: 2 } in list a
Matching element is found in a (by physical address)
```

Comment: Added a simple demo [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8674c3f33de133bd) // And here's a version that uses the scoped allocator trick to pass the outer allocator for use in the members of `my_big_struct`: [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/76419bda0811c162)